# Why did jqGrid disable the rest of my page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid calling a controller action (returning JSON to jqGrid).
When my grid gets populated, everything but the "table body" gets disabled, as if table body is shown via some modal window:
[image: example]

This is my js code to init the grid, and the html:

```
<head>
    <title>Insert</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8.1/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />    
    <script src="/Scripts/EditorHookup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script src="../../Scripts/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      var gridimgpath = '/content/themes/base/images';
      var gridDataUrl = '/Home/JsonPosloviForDate';
      var jsonDate =  "\/Date(1309816800000)\/";      
      var date = eval(jsonDate.replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//gi, "new Date($1)"));      
      $(function () {
         jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: gridDataUrl + '?currDate=' + date.toJSON(),
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Šifra posla', 'Vrsta posla', 'Partner', 'Opis', 'Broj sati'],
            colModel: [
               { name: 'SifPosao', index: 'SifPosao', width: 50, align: 'left' },
               { name: 'kratVrstaPosao', index: 'kratVrstaPosao', width: 100, align: 'left' },
               { name: 'nazPartner', index: 'nazPartner', width: 100, align: 'left' },
               { name: 'opis', index: 'opis', width: 100, align: 'left' },
               { name: 'brSati', index: 'brSati', width: 100, align: 'left' },
                     ],
            rowNum: 20,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            imgpath: gridimgpath,
            height: 'auto',
            width: '700',
            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
            sortname: 'SifPosao',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            caption: "Poslovi"
         });
      }); 
   </script>
  
</head>
<body>
...    
<table id="list" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
<div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
...   
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are [loadui](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) parameter of jqGrid which allow you to manage how the grid will be blocked. You can try to use `loadui:'disable'` to verify that it is the problem which you has.

Nevertheless the behavior which you describe seems me strange. jqGrid uses `<div>` as overlay and the div has additional class with the name 'loading'. You should verify your CSS whether you have name conflict and use the same class name for another purpose.

By the way I recommend you to review the jqGrid parameters and HTML markup which you use.

- The parameter `imgpath` will be not used since version 3.5 of jqGrid (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:upgrade_from_3.4.x_to_3.5)). Do you really use a retro version of jqGrid? If not you should remove `imgpath`.
- You should remove property `align: 'left'` from `colModel` because the default value of `align` is already 'left' (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options))
- You should remove `class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"` from the `<table id="list">` and `class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"` from the `<div id="pager">`. the settings was needed in "retro" versions of jqGrid, but not now (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#html_file) an HTML example).
- It is better to use `pager: '#pager'` instead of `pager: jQuery('#pager')`.
- Instead of constructing `url: gridDataUrl + '?currDate=' + date.toJSON()` it is better to use two parameters: `url: gridDataUrl` and `postData: {currDate: date.toJSON()}` or event better `postData: {currDate: function() { return date.toJSON(); } }`. In case of usage of functions inside of `postData` the value of the property will be evaluated **on every grid load/refresh** (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819) for more information). If you do want construct `url` manually like yoou currently do you need use [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp) or [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/): `url: gridDataUrl + '?currDate=' + encodeURIComponent(date.toJSON())` or `url: gridDataUrl + '?' + jQuery.param({currDate:date.toJSON()})`.
- you should never use `eval`.

**UPDATED**: I didn't found in the example which you send the jqGrid CSS. If I replace the block with all CSS and JavaScript files with the following lines

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.1.1/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.1.1/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.1.1/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
```

the described problem is not exist.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the comprehensive answer.
Unfortunatelly, I had no luck.
I've done everything you said. 
Changed my HTML ids, removed all other CSS, still the same.
I've experimented with loadui but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

The behaviour is the same in IE9, FF and Chrome :(.
Although, sometimes the pager gets enabled and when I move to next page it disables and everything is "locked up" then.

Firebug shows no bugs, no errors in the console, GET requests are returning proper JSON (that indeed get rendered).

Comment: @user819023: If you have the page online and post me the url I could look at it and try to find the reason. If you have overlay during the initial loading of grid data even if you use `loadui:'disable'`, than the overlay should probably come not from jqGrid. Which other plugins you use on the same page?

Comment: I just deployed it to: http://161.53.18.3:81/temp
(I've changed Site.css to Site123.css (not existing) on purpose.)

Comment: @igorludi: Sorry, but I can't access the URL now. Is is still active?

Comment: Even better, I' ve made a local array version. You can download it from here: https://rapidshare.com/files/1162739957/debuggrid.zip 
One remark thought:
The rowcount/pager is not accurate, but this way pager get enabled(?)
Just delete rows 21, 22... in the temp.htm to see the pager disabled too.
Thanks for staying on this...

Comment: @igorludi: The link which you send me don't permit to download the file without registration including the payment. It would be easier if you just send it me per email: oleg.kiriljuk@ok-soft-gmbh.com

Comment: It's not really so, you should just close the payment dialog and hit the "FREE DOWNLOAD".
I'm writing this for others, and I'll also send it to you to you email.

Comment: @igorludi: I updated my answer. In the list of files which you sent there are no jqgrid.css. Instead of that there are strange `Site123.htm` file as CSS. All JavaScript files are renamed, so it is difficult to analyse it. If one remove all JavaScript and CSS files which you use and include only the files which are needed all work without any problem.

Comment: So I was missing a single CSS. 
Thanks Oleg.

Comment: I bet the css missing was the jqgrid one. I got the same issue.

Comment: @Matthieu: Missing of either `jquery-ui.css` or `ui.jqgrid.css` follows to serious problems. Both CSS are really required.

Comment: @Oleg: true but testing it a bit got me to 'ui.jqgrid.css' missing => greyed out page till begining of grid, 'jquery-ui.css' missing => ugly grid without theming. Makes it easier to find the culprit :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and added

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.trirand.net/aspnetmvc/Content/themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />
```

now works